# Variables are logged differently depending on whether they are passed through onclick functionality or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure there's a very reasonable answer to this but I can't figure it out.
I have the following code:

```
function setMarkup(data) {
     response += "<div class='column' style='float: right;'>
                   <span style='pointer: cursor;' onclick='logText(\""+data+"\")'>Switch Out</span>
                </div>";
     console.log(data);
}
function logText(data){
     console.log(data);
}

$.ajax({
        url: "api.url.com",
        method: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            setMarkup(JSON.parse(data));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);

        }
    });
```

Where `data` is a json object. The output in the console of `console.log(data)` in `setMarkup` function is the proper json format. The output of the `logText` function when called by the `onclick` functionality is `[object Object]`. If I change `onclick='logText(\""+data+"\")'` to `onclick='logText("+data+")'`, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Any explanation as to why the `onclick` functionality outputs a different response than what gets output in the `setMarkup` function would be appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE --as per @IAmDranged answer which means my question has to slightly change--

The above code works when using one api but then  as soon as I change to my other api which has a slightly different format, it breaks and gives me the `Uncaught SyntaxError`. Also, a slight update to the code above. My onclick code is `onclick='logText("+JSON.stringify(data)+")'` I tried to simplyify it before as I didn't think it would matter when asking the question but clearly it does.

UPDATE 2
The difference between the two api's is the first one has the format:
`{"id":{"0":"10001","1":"10002",..."19":"10020"},"name":{"0":"name1","1":"name2"..."19":"name20"},"price":{"0":"20.45","1":"32.54"..."19":"17.98"}}`

And the second one has the format:
`{"id":{"0":"10001","1":"10002",..."49":"10050"},"name":{"0":"name1","1":"name2"..."49":"name50"},"price":{"0":"20.45","1":"32.54"..."49":"17.98"}, "img_url":{"0":"url1","1":"url2"..."49":"url50"},"img_url_thumbnail":{"0":"urlthumb1","1":"urlthumb2"..."49":"urlthumb50"}}`

So clearly the second one has a whole lot more data. When I remove keys 20 to 49 in the second one, the code works as expected. Is there some limit in terms of number of characters that can be set to a function when using onclick funcationality? I found the crossover point is the first 43 keys work but as soon as there are 44 keys or more then I get the error.

Comment: We can't tell how or why your functions are called.

Comment: I have updated the question to show how the `setMarkup` function is called

Answer (score 1):

`onclick='logText(\""+data+"\")'` will be rendered as `onclick='logText(data)'`

meanwhile

`onclick='logText("+data+")'` will be rendered as `onclick='logText("+data+")'`, which gives you that error

you might use your browser inspection tool, to inspect html markup produced by setMarkup function.

you can also use `console.log(response)` inside your setMarkup function

Answer (score 1):

This is all about the context in which the data object is used.

When used as part of a string expression, the javascript engine will essentially try to coerce the object to a primitive value. This will essentially result in calling the object *toString()* method, which by default - ie as defined on *Object.prototype* - will return something along the lines of *[object stringTag]*, where *stringTag* is essentially the class from which the object is instantiated - which will be *Object* in this case. This is all handled by the javascript engine according to rules defined by the ECMAScript specification.

*Console.log()* behaves differently. Its behaviour isn't actually defined by the ECMAScript specification but by the host environment, and depends on the particular implementation. In most browser environments I think, it will output a custom string representation of a live reference to the actual object.

Comment: I didn't know that. That explains the reason for the different responses from console.log depending on where it is getting called. Thanks for that explanation. Given your answer, this now slightly changes my question as the whole reason I've encounted this error is that I have changed from one api to another. I have updated my question accordingly. Thanks for your help with this